# Установка cookie с помощью echo с сервера PHP силами JS при авторизации

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookie, echo

Всем привет.
Код приводить не буду - вопрос на безопасность
.
Стоит ли делать вот так:
- При авторизации пользователя клиент(**js**) обращается к серверу по **ajax**(`fetch`)

- Сервер(**php**) вместо `setCookie` отправляет хэшированные временные логин и пароль с помощью `echo`

- Клиент их принимает и записывает с помощью `document.cookie`

Мне так удобнее с точки зрения организации кода.

Приемлемый ли это вариант с точки зрения безопасности?

Спасибо!

Comment: Приемлемый. Непонятно только зачем вы хэшируете временный логин и пароль. Есть такая вещь как токен.

Comment: ArchDemon, поясни, пожалуйста, о каком именно токене идёт речь? Я думал, что токен это и есть какое-то случайное длинное слово, которое позволяет мне идентифицировать клиента.

Comment: Ну я впервые слышу про временные логин и пароль. Обычно передают токен - случайный набор символов, как вы верно заметили.

Answer (score 0):

Разницы устанавливать куки силами `php` `setcookie` или отправлять с помощью `echo` с точки зрения безопасности нет.